# Geometric interpretation of metric

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry

For metric in $\mathbb R^2$ (polar coordinates) Pythagorean triangle elements can be visualized in a differential form as seen at top yellow triangle. This happens for metric:

$$ ds^2= dr^2 +(r d \theta)^2 $$
By applying Euler-Lagrange equation of calculus of variations we have DE and a particular integral curve (primed on $\theta)$

$$ r^2+ 2r{'2}-r r ^{''} = 0,\quad r= \sec \,\theta$$
We have two sides for $r d \theta, dr $ and a hypotenuse, these are well known.

Now consider the metric with its second term subtracted instead :

$$ ds^2= dr^2 -(r d \theta)^2 $$

The DE and its integral curve solution turn out to be

$$ r^2 - 2r{'2} + r r ^{''} = 0,\quad r= sech \,\theta$$

and they are shown in the smaller yellow triangle at left.

[image: Metrics Geom Interpretation]

However the third side is not seen shorter along $ r= sech \, \theta $ curve  but still *remains as the longer hypotenuse* as for the earlier Pythagorean metric case.

How can we geometrically interpret sides/ hypotenuse directly mapping or reflecting the definition metric from which the curve arises ?

I  had expected side/hypotenuse swap for the latter metric but does not show that way.. nor could I bring in some workaround to justify the situation, so far not successful in a case that at the outset would seem elementary.

If it helps angle $\psi$  to radius vector and $ r=sech\, \theta$ is given by

$$ \tan \psi= \coth \theta$$

I am trying to see how one may construct a differential right triangle with sides
$$  (r, r^{ '}, hypotenuse{ '}) $$

with this metric also, as it is so easy to construct it with the Pythagorean metric in polar co-ordinate form.

Thanks for your thoughts and guidance. Regards

Comment: Shorter than what? Integral curve of what? If you mean the geodesic flow, remember that in indefinite metric, geodesic ≠ length minimizing.

Comment: I wish to see a differential right triangle of three quantities $ r, r^{'} $ and the hypotenuse constructed/shown.

Comment: Where you wrote $r^2$ you probably meant $dr^2$. The natural interpretation of the metric $ds^2 = dr^2 - (r d\theta)^2$ is as the exterior of the light cone in 2 dimensional Minkowski space. In 2 dimensional Minkowski space you have the metric $ds^2 = dx^2 - dt^2$, and restricted to the region $x > |t|$ you can define $r = \sqrt{x^2 - t^2}$ and $\theta$ such that $x = r\cosh \theta$ and $t = r\sinh \theta$.

Comment: I vaguely remember seeing some paper developing the "plane geometry" of 2d Minkowski space, but I can't find it right now. Maybe you have better luck.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. ( fixed the typo.) . Actually I looked at this metric when first studying hyperbolic geometry as the simplest hyperbolic 2D space model. I shall search 2d Minkowski now per your suggestion. That we cannot make a triangle either with straight or curvilinear sides.. is what  still troubles me.